# ¿Por que la API de OneSignal me arroja este error?

Tags: php, json

Cree una aplicación de notificaciones con la API de OneSignal, y hace un momento todo me funcionaba excelente. Pero derrepente me arroja este error:

```
{
"response": {
       "status": 400,
       "error": "There was a problem in the JSON you submitted: unexpected characters after the JSON document at line 1, column 1 [parse.c:590]"
}
}
```

Este es mi código php:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
function sendMessage(){
$content = array(
"en" => 'Hi'
);
$fields = [
'app_id' => "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxx",
'include_player_ids' => [
"xxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxx-xxxx"
],
'contents' => $content
];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
CURLOPT_URL => "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications",
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
CURLOPT_HEADER => FALSE,
CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $fields,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE
]);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return json_decode($response);
}
$response = sendMessage();
$return["response"] = $response;
$return = json_encode($return, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo $return;
?>
```

El `manifest.json`:

```
{
      "name": "Page Name",
      "short_name": "Short Page Name",
      "start_url": "/",
      "display": "standalone",
      "gcm_sender_id": "xxxxxxx"
}
```

Aquí les dejo la [documentación](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v3.0/reference#create-notification) de la API de OneSignal.

Comment: ¿Podrías aportar el contenido del json enviado? Tiene pinta de que estás enviando un carácter no válido.

Comment: Pues no tengo idea a que json se refiere el código. Probablemente sea el manifest.json donde tengo incluido el nombre de la 'app, y el id.

Comment: Ya añadí el `manifest.json`

Comment: Aquí te dejo la documentación sobre el archivo [manifest.json](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-sdk-setup-https) de la API OneSignal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final yo mismo lo resolví, el problema radicaba en que no estaba utilizando la función `json_encode` en la variable `$fields`.

Y mi código quedo así:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
function sendMessage(){
$fields = [
'app_id' => "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxx",
'include_player_ids' => [
"xxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxx-xxxx"
],
'contents' => [
'en' => 'Hi'
]
];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
CURLOPT_URL => "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications",
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
'Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
],
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
CURLOPT_HEADER => FALSE,
CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($fields),
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE
]);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return json_decode($response);
}
$response = sendMessage();
$return["response"] = $response;
$return = json_encode($return, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo $return;
?>
```